# Chef and PostgreSql

Tags: postgresql, chef, amazon-rds

With amazon annoucing postgresql service in RDS, can we setup chef-server(11) with amazon rds postgresql database, rather than using the default databse that gets installed with the omnibus installer. I have read that we can achieve same by configuring chef-server.rb file and then reconfiguring the chef-server, but can't get what setttings to specify in the chef-server.rb file. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that it's actual for you since question asked 5 months ago, but you need to disable local pgsql service:

```
postgresql['enable'] = false
```

And set connection options:

```
postgresql['vip'] = '<IP ADDRESS or HOSTNAME of DB server>'
postgresql['port'] = PGSQL_PORT
postgresql['sql_user'] = '<USERNAME>'
postgresql['sql_password'] = '<PASSWORD>'
```

And finally run reconfiguration to generate new configuration files and restart necessary services:

```
chef-server-ctl reconfigure
```

Don't forget to import DB dump to your RDS instance, I'm not sure that chef will create all the things in this case.